# Need help to Webservice in Axis2 with https in java

Tags: java, web-service

I have written my webservice with HTTPS. But as per my requirement I should provide authentication. So thought of going with HTTPS SSL. could anyone help me with steps like moving HTTP to HTTPS and SSL certification part with step by step

I did by adding below in service and axis XML files:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/root/my_workspace/server.keystore"              keystorePass="changeit"/>

<transportReceiver name="http" class= "org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">  
   <parameter name="port">8080</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
<transportReceiver name="https" class= "org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">  
   <parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

But I don't want to access through HTTP. How can I restrict?

Also I created the WDSL request via Eclipse, the value tag starts with "q0" and response has return tag as well. So how can I avoid and go with custom req/response?

Can anyone guide me, step by step, to go ahead with this?

Comment: You can configure tomcat to only use HTTPS.
you can google, there are a lot:
http://www.itworld.com/development/79351/how-configure-tomcat-always-require-https